# How to crop an image without using internal camera cropping

Tags: android, image, android-studio, crop

I want to display a cropped  image in an `imageview` which is displayed as preview and after displaying it as preview, now I want to crop it again and show it in `imageView` but I don't want to make a use of internal camera cropping and while cropping I don't want to fix the height and width.

Comment: please explain a bit more your question is unclear to me, If possible use diagrams to elaborate what you want, also show us what you tried yet.

Comment: i think you want to crop image not imageview.

Comment: its just i want to crop an image but without using the internal camera cropping . I want to develop a new code for cropping in my application. Sorry i dont have any diagram to explain . this is all i could explain to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned any specific requirement, so i am gonna go with a circular image cropping example to show , how it's works . So image is just like a pic drawn on some paper so what you need to change the image in real life?, `Canvas`,`Paint`,`Shapes` etc.Same things are available in `android` and `Java` through various API's.

You can use`bitmap` which is a `matrix` of `pixels` on which you can do your painting , cropping , styling etc using 'Canvas' class.

Steps :
1. Get the bitmap from your image or from drawable etc
 
2. Create a new bitmap with `Config.ARGB_8888` mean set alpha,RGB channel to 8 bits size of new bitmap for efficiency.
3. Create a new `BitmapShader` for rounded corners styling.
4. Create a new `Paint` which hold the style and color info to be drawn.
5. Create a new `Canvas` which handles the draw operation using inputs .
6. Call 'drawCircle' on  `Canvas` object with `Paint` and radius .
7. You are done ! Now you can study about these APIs to fulfill your requirements.

```
Bitmap bitmap = yourImageBitmap; // step 1
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // step 2

BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);// step 3
Paint paint = new Paint(); // step 4
        paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth picture
Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap); // step 5 
c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint); // step 6    

myImageView.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use ImageMagick.

https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick

It's a high quality, flexible image manipulation library.  I haven't used it in Android, but from the command line and C# it's pretty straightforward.  I believe the `MagickImage` class is the main one you'll need.